# How to stop binding to AMQP default exchange?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Every time I bind an AMQP queue to an exchange it automatically seems to bind to the 'default' direct exchange.

Here's the code in using a rabbitMQ server and node.js:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost'});

connection.on('ready', function(){
    var q = connection.queue('test_queue_name');
    var exc = connection.exchange('test_exchange', { autoDelete:true });
    q.bind('test_exchange', 'test.key');
});
```

Here's the console output when using the "rabbitmqctl list_bindings" command:

```
Listing bindings ...
        exchange        test_queue_name queue   test_queue_name []
test_exchange   exchange        test_queue_name queue   test.key        []
...done.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RabbitMQ automatically binds every queue to the default exchange with a routing key the same as the queue name.

From the [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default)

> The default exchange is a direct exchange with no name (empty string) pre-declared by the broker. It has one special property that makes it very useful for simple applications: **every queue that is created is automatically bound to it with a routing key which is the same as the queue name.**

I'm pretty sure this is part of the AMQP spec.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the default exchange is bound to even if another binding is named? In the tutorials when 'rabbitmqctl list_bindings' is used it doesn't show the default exchange to have a binding...

Comment: I took the extra `...` in the tutorial to mean they omitted some information. (assuming you're looking at this one: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html)

Comment: The AMQP spec talks about "automatic mode", where the broker must provide a default exchange, and that queues have a default binding to it. It doesn't appear to take a position about whether this is *required* for queues with specified bindings.

Comment: When opening the management UI, under "default exchange", it clearly says "The default exchange is implicitly bound to every queue, with a routing key equal to the queue name. It is not possible to explicitly bind to, or unbind from the default exchange. It also cannot be deleted."